# How to pronounce the word 月 (Yue) in English？

Tags: pronunciation

Could anybody help me to pronounce the Chinese word 月 (Yue)?

Is there any word in English whose pronunciation is similar to this?

Comment: I believe you can find an online dictionary with sound. As for English, English doesn't have the same vowel, it's hard to define a similar sound.

Answer (score 2):

Try yoo (yü) from 'yoohoo' and eh from 'Eh? What?'

yoo-eh

After j, q, x and y u is always ü, although it is not written as ü, which is easy for Germans, but not so easy for the English to say, it is like oo in 'shoo shoo'(go away), an Umlaut u = ü

Answer (score 0):

月 is written as “yue” in Pinyin. It can be broken into two parts: initial and final. (IPA is also: /ɥe/ | /ɥ/ = y | /e/ = ue). Y [is said to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Mandarin) an approximation of the **hu** in the French word “huit.” Ue is said to be similar to the “**e**” in the English word “hey.”

You’d be better off just repeatedly listening to the Chinese word being pronounced and trying to imitate the pronunciation though. [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/%E6%9C%88/#zh) has a good collection of people reading words that you can check out.